# Type class Read, is it posibble to read a function by it name?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Suppose I have this function:

```
squared x = x ** 2
```

and I want to read it from the console, and apply it. Is possible to do something like this?:

```
gchi> (read("squared) :: Int -> Int) 4
```

Comment: No. At least not in the general case.

Comment: You can interpret the function using the hint package.

Comment: `squared` is a variable name; `Int -> Int` is just the type. What's the *value* of the function? That's what `read` needs to produce from a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; in general, this is not possible. To see why, think about a few of the situations which could occur if this functionality existed:

- Let’s say you redefine `(+) a b = a - b`. Now, should `read "(+)"` be the `(+)` from the Prelude, or your redefined `(+)` operator?
- If you do `read "foobar"`, and `foobar` has not yet been defined as a function, then what should this return? Then if `foobar` is defined somewhere else in the module, should this return value suddenly change?
- If you add `import Prelude ()` to the top of your program, which removes all of the imports from Prelude, should `read "preludeFunctionName"` stop working?

Now, none of these problems are dealbreakers in and of themselves — in another language, you could still define a `read` function taking those into account. The problem in this case is *referential transparency* : the property that a non-`IO` function should always return the same output given the same input(s). Since the type of `read` is `Read a => String -> a`, as opposed to `Read a => String -> IO a`, you can’t make an instance of `read` like you want, given that the above function can give a different answer depending on the exact context in which it is run. (e.g. `read "foobar"` and `let foobar = (+1) in read "foobar"` would give different answers to the same function call.)

On the other hand, if you still want to have this functionality, there is one way of getting it. The [`hint`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) package allows Haskell code to be interpreted at runtime, and so you can use this functionality to write a function like this:

```hs
-- Warning: the following code is untested
-- Please comment if you find any errors!
import Language.Haskell.Interpreter

readFn :: Typeable a
       => [ModuleName]   -- ^ Modules to search
       -> String         -- ^ Function to read
       -> a              -- ^ Witness for the type a
       -> IO (Either InterpreterError a)
readFn m f w = runInterpreter $ do
    setImports m
    interpret f w
```

The above function can be used as follows:

```hs
readFn ["Prelude"] "(+)" (as :: Num a => a -> a -> a)
```

Where [`as`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.9.0.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v:as) is from `Language.Haskell.Interpreter`.

Comment: I find myself scratching my head about this answer. Suppose I write `instance Read (Double -> Double) where read "squared" = squared; read _ = error "no parse"`. This doesn't break referential transparency, so that knocks out one of your objections. As an implementation, it seems to provide answers to all three questions in bullet points, too. So what, *exactly*, is bad about this implementation?

Comment: @DanielWagner There isn’t really anything _bad_ about that implementation as such. However, it only works with `squared`. If you attempt to use `read` with any other function, your implementation fails, so it doesn’t really answer your problem. I was talking specifically about an implementation which works with _any_ function name.

Comment: @DanielWagner There is also another problem I forgot to mention in my answer. In Haskell, `read` is meant to be the inverse of `show`; if you `show` something and then `read` it, you get back to where you started. So you would also need to write a `show` function which, given a function implementation, finds its name — which is probably impossible.

Comment: The first comment I find convincing -- and you should make *that* the objection you put in your answer, not these other red herrings! The second comment I find unconvincing; it is common to implement `Show` without implementing `Read`, so I see no reason that the roundtripping law should also imply that you must choose to implement both classes if you choose to implement one.

Comment: @DanielWagner My first comment related specifically to your first comment, which is why I didn’t include it in my answer. As for my second comment, I do think you’re right about that one. After thinking about this a bit more, I think the most fundamental reason you can’t implement an instance of `Read` like this is that `read` does not take place in `IO`, so any implementation along your lines would break referential transparency.